# admin type on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble of my admin type

in my db I have a type field which has 1 and 2 value
1 is for admin
2 is for cashier

now here's my controller

```
<?php  
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  
 class Main extends CI_Controller {  
      //functions  
      function login()  
      {  
           //http://localhost/tutorial/codeigniter/main/login  
           $data['title'] = 'Lending System Login';  
           $this->load->view("login", $data);  
      }  
      function login_validation()  
      {  
           $this->load->library('form_validation');  
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');  
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');  
           if($this->form_validation->run())  
           {  
                //true  
                $username = $this->input->post('username');  
                $password = $this->input->post('password');  
                //model function  
                $user = $this->load->model('main_model');  
                if($this->main_model->can_login($username, $password))  
                {  
                     $session_data = array(  
                          'username'     =>     $username  
                     );  
                     $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);  
                     redirect(base_url() . 'main/enter');  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');  
                     redirect(base_url() . 'main/login');  
                }  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                //false  
                $this->login();  
           }  
      }  
      function enter(){  
           if($this->session->userdata('username') != '')  
           {
            //check what type 
            //1 - admin
            //2 - cashier
              if($this->session->userdata('type') == 1)
              {
                // echo '<h2>Welcome - '.$this->session->userdata('username').'</h2>';  
                // echo '<label><a href="'.base_url().'main/logout">Logout</a></label>';
                redirect(base_url(). 'main/admin');  
              }
              else
              {
                redirect(base_url(). 'main/cashier');
              }

           }  
           else  
           {  
                redirect(base_url() . 'main/login');  
           }  
      }  

      function logout()  
      {  
           $this->session->unset_userdata('username');  
           redirect(base_url() . 'main/login');  
      }  
 }
```

now here is my model `can_login`

```
<?php

class Main_model extends CI_Model
{

    function can_login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

my problem is that I couldn't get the admin type because i didn't type it it's already in the database and my problem is that how can I have an admin type

Please can someone please help me with this . I'm new to codeigniter

thank you.

Comment: Is there a `type` column in `user` table ?

Comment: @imoverflow yes

Comment: only `if($query->num_rows() > 0)` not enough, either put condition for admin or check with result that login user is `admin` or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.

what i did was this

```
 $session_data = array(  
        'username' => $username,
        'type' => $type  
 );  
 $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);     
 if($this->session->userdata('username') != '')
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('type') == '1')
   {
       redirect(base_url(). 'main/admin');
   }
  else
   {
       redirect(base_url(). 'main/cashier');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column called `user_type` to define user role, Follow this steps

1) In your model, modify this

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return $query->row_array(); // Send data from model to controller
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

2) In Controller, modify this

```
$user_data = $this->main_model->can_login($username, $password)
if($user_data)  
{  
     $session_data = array(  
          'username' =>     $user_data['username'],
          'type'     =>     $user_data['user_type'],   
     );  
     $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);  
     redirect(base_url() . 'main/enter');  
}  
else  
{  
   $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');  
   redirect(base_url() . 'main/login');  
}
```

Comment: this has an error sir saying Message: Undefined property: Main::$main_model

Filename: controllers/main.php

Line Number: 35

Comment: Load your model `main_model` like this `$this->load->model('main_model'); `